# How to resolve error while implementing Jquery.SpellChecker in .net application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, spell-checking

I tried to implement Jquery.Spell.Checker in asp.net application but it gives error as shown in following image.

[image]

Anyone suggest me how to resolve it.

[**CLICK HERE TO SEE THE SAMPLE**](http://jsbin.com/urizox/16)

PS:

I have done changes in my application but still doesn't working and display alert message as per above image.Please let me know if i was missing something.The code given below:

**LINK:**

```
<link href="JQuerySpellChecker/spellchecker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuerySpellChecker/jquery.spellchecker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
        margin: 1em;
        font-family: 'lucida grande',helvetica,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
#textarea-example {
        width: 562px;
}
textarea {
        font-size: 90%;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        border-color: #888888 #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #888888;
        border-style: solid;
        height: 20em;
        width: 550px;
}
button {
        font-size: 90%;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.loading {
        padding: 0.5em 8px;
        display: none;
        font-size: small;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="textarea-example">
    <p>
        <label for="text-content">Add your own text and check the spelling.</label>
    </p>
    <textarea id="text-content" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
    <div>
        <button id="check-textarea">Check Spelling</button>&nbsp;
        <span class="loading">loading..</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// check the spelling on a textarea
$("#check-textarea").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading").show();
        $("#text-content")
        .spellchecker({
                url: "CheckSpelling.aspx",       // default spellcheck url
                lang: "en",                     // default language 
                engine: "google",               // pspell or google
                addToDictionary: false,         // display option to add word to dictionary (pspell only)
                wordlist: {
                        action: "after",               // which jquery dom insert action
                        element: $("#text-content")    // which object to apply above method
                },      
                suggestBoxPosition: "below",    // position of suggest box; above or below the highlighted word
                innerDocument: false            // if you want the badwords highlighted in the html then set to true
        })
        .spellchecker("check", function(result){
                // spell checker has finished checking words
                $(".loading").hide();
                // if result is true then there are no badly spelt words
                if (result) {
                        alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
                }
        });
});
// you can ignore this; if document is viewed via subversion in google code then re-direct to demo page
if (/jquery-spellchecker\.googlecode\.com/.test(window.location.hostname) && /svn/.test(window.location)) {
        window.location = 'http://spellchecker.jquery.badsyntax.co.uk/';
}
```

**CheckSpelling.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = Request["str"];
    //string str = "goood";
    if (str != null)
    {
        string url = "https://www.google.com";
        string path = "/tbproxy/spell?lang=en&hl=en";
        // setup XML request
        string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
        xml += "<spellrequest textalreadyclipped=\"0\" ignoredups=\"0\" ignoredigits=\"1\" ignoreallcaps=\"1\">";
        xml += "<text>" + str + "</text></spellrequest>";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(xml);
        WebProxy objWP = new WebProxy("address", 1978);
        objWP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mysystemname", "password");
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url + path);
        request.Proxy = objWP;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Send the data.
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();
        response.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(responseFromServer, "<c o=\"([^\"]*)\" l=\"([^\"]*)\" s=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)</c>");
        if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
            Response.Write(result[0].Value);
    }
    Response.Write("Failed");
}
```

Comment: The URL `http://jsbin.com/urizox/checkspelling.php` is non-existent.

Comment: In the ASPX file, try changing the line string str = Request["str"]; to say string str = Request["text"];

Answer (score 1):

You need to write yourself an ASP version of the included PHP server side file.  Essentially, the server side component proxies a request off to Google or uses a PHP spell checker.  Since you wouldn't really want to convert the whole of the Pspell library, I would recommend simply wrapping up the call to Google's spell check site.

i.e. Create an ASPX page and add the following code to it

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(Object src, EventArgs e)
{
    var str = Request["str"];
    if (str != null)
    {
        var url = "https://www.google.com";
        var path = "/tbproxy/spell?lang=en&hl=en";

        // setup XML request
        var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
        xml += "<spellrequest textalreadyclipped=\"0\" ignoredups=\"0\" ignoredigits=\"1\" ignoreallcaps=\"1\">";
        xml += "<text>" + str + "</text></spellrequest>";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(xml);

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url + path);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Send the data.
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        // Get the response.
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);

        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();
        response.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches(responseFromServer, "<c o=\"([^\"]*)\" l=\"([^\"]*)\" s=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)</c>");
        if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
            Response.Write(result[0].Value);
    }
    Response.Write("Failed");
}
</script>
```

Then change the call in the js to call your new aspx file rather than the 'checkspelling.php'

Comment: thanks dude for yr response.Can u tell me how to convert it to ASP.NET or JavaScript code as i don't know PHP Or Should i take help from a PHP Developer.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with an ASP version of the PHP code which should return the same results.

Comment: I have done changes in application as per our conversation but not working.Please see the updated question.

Comment: I pass goood text and i got result[0].Value ="<c o="0" l="5" s="1">good Good goody God god</c>" but after completing request still alert message displaying.

Comment: It seems the JS code is expecting a JSON response from the server.  The PHP didn't look like it did that, but that could be my error in reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late for you, but for any one else trying to resolve this problem, Jack Yang has produced an ASP implementation of checkspelling.php it can be found at

https://github.com/jackmyang/jQuery-Spell-Checker-for-ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

The plugin only does the client-side code. You'll have to supply it with your ASP script's URL.

[Read the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation).

Comment: I added checkspelling.php in application but still giving error.Do i need to install PHP5 also?

Comment: You've stated in your question that you're using .net. In that case, simply adding the `checkspelling.php` won't help you, since your server has no way of parsing the PHP code. So, yes, you do have to install PHP in order to use a PHP script. However, mixing the 2 will cause you too much of a headache.

Comment: If this is the case then can u suggest me any other free spell checker for asp.net?